# GLUT window turns black "(not responding)" when CPU is busy

Tags: glut, cpu-usage

I'm programming a raytracer and use GLUT to display the result. I render the the image in subblocks and after rendering each subblock i update the view.

What happens is that i see the render progress, but after some seconds, the render window turns black and the window caption reads "(not responding)". the renderprocess however continues to run (at 100% cpu usage) and outputs progressinfo on the console output. once the rendering is finished, the GLUT window turns back to normal and displays the image.

What can I do in order to keep the window responding during the rendering process so that it doesn't turn black?

Thanks!

//edit: I aparently block my mainthread while waiting for the render threads:

```
while(true){
    if(m_activeRenderThreads==0)
        break;
    ::WaitForSingleObject(updateEvent->m_hObject, 200);
    notifyObservers(); //inherited from IFunctionObservable
}
```

notifyObservers() calls:

```
update(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0,0,resX,resY);
    glRasterPos2i(-1,-1);
    glDrawPixels(resX, resY, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, renderBuffer);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

this last function works only if I call it from the mainthread. calling it through the renderthreads doesn't update my window

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is put all your processing in a separate thread; the main GUI thread should only be used for responding to GUI events and painting the window, but should not do any intensive computations. So... in a separate thread, paint to a buffer, and then every so often you should schedule on the main GUI thread for this buffer to be copied into the UI.

Comment: it's what i do. when starting to render, i create n new threads (n=#of cpu's) and raytrace only in those threads

Comment: i think i found the problem. I'm creating my renderthreads using MFC. in the mainthread I wait for those threads in a while-loop (see above) to notify me that they finished a subarea of the rendering and to update the GLUT window. I don't know how I can update the GLUT window with another thread than the mainthread